# How to add the values which has same name in angular8 using rxjs?

Tags: rxjs, angular8

html code:
here i am calling kgs like 10kgs or 20kgs etc.. i would like to add the values which has same name as a parameter. this code is not working for me.

```
<p>Total Materials</p>

  <div class="add-div">
    <div *ngFor="let item of allMaterials">
           <div class="file-name">
     <div>{{item.title}}</div>
     <div>{{item.wt_in_kgs_per_unit}}{{item.uom}}</div> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

component.ts:

```
 updateMaterials(){
    this.allMaterials = []
    this.materialList.map((item : any) => {
      this.allMaterials =[...this.allMaterials, ...item]});
      console.log(this.allMaterials);

  => from this line the code is not working...
   const x = from(this.allMaterials).pipe(map(data => {
        data.groupBy((x:any) => x.title)
        .flatMap(group => {
        return group.reduce((acc,currentValue)=>{
          acc.wt_in_kgs_per_unit = acc.wt_in_kgs_per_unit + currentValue.wt_in_kgs_per_unit;
          return acc;
        })
      })
    .subscribe(d => this.groupedData = d);
      })   
      )

      console.log(x)
      console.log(this.allMaterials);
```

Comment: Hi @Rekha. Welcome to StackOverflow. What exactly are your trying to do, what did you already try and what are the errors you are getting.
Please refer to [how to ask awesome questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) enable us to help you properly

Answer (score 0):

```
this.allMaterials = []
    this.materialList.map((item : any) => {
      this.allMaterials =[...this.allMaterials, ...item]});
      console.log(this.allMaterials);
```

is this your way of copying the array materialList to allMaterials? It is a rather inefficient way when you could just use

```
this.allMaterials = [...this.materialList];
```

The next mess looks like a strange attempt to use rxjs to group something that is already an array. What are you expecting x to be? A subscription?

You could try

```
from(this.allMaterials).pipe(
  groupBy((x:any) => x.title),
  map(group => group.reduce((acc,currentValue)=> {
      acc.wt_in_kgs_per_unit = acc.wt_in_kgs_per_unit + currentValue.wt_in_kgs_per_unit;
      return acc;
    }))
```

But I would just work with the array outside of rxjs.

Comment: thank you so much for this solution.. but In this group.reduce gives me an error(property does not exist)

Comment: this code is not working for me. could you please suggest new solution for this problem ?  this is a nested array, when i click same parameter in both the arrays, the kg of the product should be added in total materials.. in my case both(same name as a product) are showing.

Comment: I have a groupBy function here that works with arrays https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-ezydzv